# Including chart based on fields in CartoDB infowindow?

Tags: carto, cartocss, carto-js

I would like to make graphs, pie charts, etc based on fields in my table within my infowindows. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I wonder if http://www.chartjs.org/ would tie into CartoDB.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cartodb.js you have [an example](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/examples/infowindow_with_graph.html) integration with google charts. Other charting libraries should work in the same way. You can see it working [here](http://cartodb.github.io/cartodb.js/examples/infowindow_with_graph.html).

The key is to call the chart function inside the infowindow template, note draw_chart call:

```
 var INFOWINDOW_TEMPLATE = [
        '<div class="cartodb-popup v2">',
        '  <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>',
        '   <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">',
        '     <div class="cartodb-popup-content">',
        '       <div id="chart_div">',
        '       <script>',
          '       draw_chart([{{content.data.pop_min}}, {{content.data.pop_max}}], "{{content.data.name}}");',
        '       </scr' + 'ipt>',
        '       </div>',
        '     </div>',
        '   </div>',
        '   <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>',
        '</div>'].join('');
```

Comment: In your example, you're using a Json.
Would it be possible to use it without?
building a map from scratch like this: cartodb.createLayer(map, {user_name: 'user', type: 'cartodb', sublayers: [{sql: 'select * from table', cartocss: cssstyle, setInteractivity: 'var1','var2','var3'}]
Thanks!