# Embedding feature chart/graph in pop-up window in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, chart

I would like to be able to embed a chart/graph of attributes for each feature within a webmap. I've had a look around and haven't found anything definitive on the [turorial](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials.html) pages of how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Editing: For the response of this answer related with CartoDB.js, please see here: [Including chart based on fields in CartoDB infowindow?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132367/including-chart-based-on-fields-in-cartodb-infowindow)

To get a workaround for the answer just by using the CartoDB Editor (and not CartoDB.js explicitly):

CartoDB hasn't still the ability to draw graphs: this means that you need to create them with other tools and then, as you say, show them in the infowindows.

Two approaches here:

- Create static graphs with any tool and save them as images. Then, you can upload those images to the Internet (or to your Dropbox public folder) and copy their direct links in a column of your CartoDB table. This will allow you to add this image in the infowindow directly with the wizards. You can use the image header template for the infowindows or you can create a custom one and insert your URL column in the src part of a img tag:

  < img src="{{url_column_name}}" />
- You can use any graph tool that let you embed your graphs as iframes. You can load iframes inside of the infowindows. In order to do this, you'd need to add the iframe code in a custom HTML template of template of the infowindow and, as in the previous case, add into a column of your table the URL or identifier for each of your elements.

This would allow you to use some HTML code as:

```
<iframe width='100%' height='520' frameborder='0' src='{{column_with_embed_url}}'></iframe>
```

Recommended readings:

- http://blog.cartodb.com/introducing-beautiful-info-windows-with-image-support/
- http://blog.cartodb.com/full-editing-of-infowindow-html/

Comment: That answer is great for CartoDB.js, this one will work fine if you're working just with the CartoDB Editor :-)

Comment: I just edited it with the API/Editor explanation. Thank you!

Comment: If I have columns A & B, I want just want to be able to click on a feature and have those two attributes displayed as a bar chart. Is this possible to achieve purely through CartoCSS editor? Without knowledge of JS nor HTML, I am struggling to know where to start

Comment: > CartoDB hasn't still the ability to draw graphs :-) By using JS, you'll also be able to retrieve the data and create some graphs with libraries like D3.js

Comment: Ok thanks for that, just wondering how I get this https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/examples/infowindow_with_graph.html to work for my webmap then. Is there some other GUI I need to use? CartoCSS editor gives me no feedback when an error is thrown

Comment: This cannot be done with CartoCSS neither inside the CartoDB Editor :-) The file you're referring to is an HTML file which is creating the data for the visualization whose URL is in the createLayer function. This visualization contains a table with columns pop_min, pop_max and name, which are the ones selected in the custom HTML infowindow template. The values of these columns are being sent to a function from a Google API inside the draw_chart method, and this method is populating the infowindow with the graph created by the library.